# Missing integration options for online accounts in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, google, gmail, online-accounts

For some reason I do not have all the plugins that should be here in online accounts(twitter option is not there by deafault but I can install it) and the options to integrate seems to be missing(Gmail and Facebook feed, etc).
The only options I get from Google is photos search plugin and google drive search plugin.
libgoa-1.0-0 is already installed.I also tried re-installing account-plugin-google and libaccount-plugin-google but it did not help. 
I recently upgraded to ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04 and this problem existed on 13.04 also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libgoa-1.0-0

Type `sudo apt-get install libgoa-1.0-0`

You will get all other online account options.

Comment: libgoa-1.0-0 is already the newest version.