# What happened to Facebook in Online Accounts - 13.10?

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

I apologize if this was previously answered, but it seems like we're not able to add Facebook as one of our "Online Accounts" all of a sudden in 13.10. I was notified today that it was unable to connect to Facebook when I logged in. I'm curious if there is a particular reason why this might be the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have to attempt to install some third part software in order to make the missing accounts to come back.

[Missing integration options for online accounts in 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424696/missing-integration-options-for-online-accounts-in-13-10)

It is all described there ^^

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed this earlier. :)